# PHP include inside loop - is it hard on disk io?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, include

Im working on a website that shows products.
The site is written in PHP.

to make it easier to maintain, I created a php code for the "product" item with thumbnail, price, etc.

I would like to know if it is hard on Disk IO to put an include file inside a foreach. Let say the array counts about 200 items.

```
foreach($wines AS $wine):
    require 'components/wine.php';
endforeach;
```

Are we still ok or there will have some hosting issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the file contain? Why include the same file 200 times?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

Regarding your question though, its probably Ok with the disk. Files imported using `require()` are also cached in precompiled bytecode the same way as the main file (if you have `OPCache` or any cache system enabled), so PHP wont read it from disk every time you include it.

**Recomendation**

I would not recommend that approach at all. I think a more recomendable approach would be to define a function that returns or displays whatever you want to show, then require the file once and call the function between the loop.

I see many downsides in your approach, like:

1. Its a bad practice, it couples your code because now this file can only be included in this file. It becomes required that the contents of the file are aware of the file that its including it, making it harder to maintain and more prone to errors in the future.
2. It can arise problems in the future, eg. if someone declares a function inside the file, it would cause a crash as requiring the file twice would redeclare the function leading to an error
3. It will cause some overhead in the execution, as PHP perform some validations and operations when a file is included

If you want more information about require or OPCache I link documentation below

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I understand the bad practice of including php file that way.
But I think instead of a function, I would use a template engine. I want to separate code and view.

Comment: Sure, if you got access to a template engine it would be much better